# python console shows less built in functions then my main program

Tags: python, pycharm

This might be a dumb question but I ran print(len(dir(**builtins**))) on my main program and got 153 functions, but while running this code (without print) on the python console I got 45. I checked and both are using the same python interpreter. So does anyone know what might be causing the problem?

Comment: What are the differences?

Comment: I don't think it really matters anymore as I was able to run the function max on the python console even though it wasn't listed in the dir function. So probably I have a visual glitch or my console just limits how much it can output.

Comment: Neither "153" nor "45" are much to output.

Comment: When I leave out the len part my console shows only 45 functions, while my main file shows 153 functions even though they're both using 3.9 python interpreter. But for some reason I can use functions on the python console that aren't listed in dir from the python console.

Comment: No idea, I get 150+ consistently, though it varied between 152, 153, 158 depending on which REPL and whether there was a `print`. One time it even changed from 152 to 153 in the same session. The docs for `dir` do warn that 
"Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an *interesting* set of names more than it tries to supply a *rigorously or consistently defined* set of names", but I can't imagine why there's such a big discrepancy for you.